# Why don't my entries get saved in the database in Django?

Tags: django

The post requests from the frontend do not get saved in the database, without any error shown. However, when I manually add entries from the admin panel, it shows on the frontend.

My index.html(form part):

```
<form class="main__input--form" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
            <p class="main__input--text">
                <textarea name="content" id="content" class="main__input--content" cols="35" rows="8" aria-label="Entry content" placeholder="Enter text here..."></textarea>
            </p>
            <button class="main__input--submit" type="submit">Vent</button>
        </form>
```

My extension of index which loops through the database entries:

```
{% for obj in all_vents %}
    <div>
        <h1>{{obj.vent}}</h1>
    </div>
        <br />
    {% endfor %}
```

My models.py:

```
class Vents(models.Model):
    vent = models.CharField(max_length=10000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.vent
```

My forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Vents

class VentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vents
        fields = ['vent']
```

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import VentForm
from .models import Vents

def ventout(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = VentForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect("ventout")
    else:
        all_vents = Vents.objects.all()
        return render(request, "ventout.html", {"all_vents": all_vents})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Views:**

```
def ventout(request): 

  all_vents = Vents.objects.all() 

  if request.method == "POST":
      form = VentForm(request.POST or None)
      if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          return redirect("ventout")
  else:
      form = VentForm()
  context = {"all_vents": all_vents, "form":form}
  return render(request, "ventout.html", context)
```

**Template:**

```
<form class="main__input--form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }} 
    <button type="submit" class="main__input--submit">Vent</button>
</form>
```

you could install/use ***"crispy_forms_tags"*** to make the form look better,

```
https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
```

if you want to go further you could install/use ***"widget_tweaks"***

```
https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your index.html from part should have `{{ form }}` form tag, as I guess.

Try Using following code

```
<form class="main__input--form" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
        <p class="main__input--text">
            <textarea name="content" id="content" class="main__input--content" 
  cols="35" rows="8" aria-label="Entry content" placeholder="Enter text here..."> 
 </textarea>
        </p>
        <button class="main__input--submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Vent</button>
 </form>
```